# Individually Extracting XML Data from an XML file using BeautifulSoup on Python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have this XML data:

```
xmlfile = '''           <Trainers>
                <Trainers name="VisitorID" value="NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231"></Trainers>
                <Trainers name="VisitorNumber" value="BR-76594823-009922"></Trainers>
                <Trainers name="ServerIndex" value="213122"></Trainers>
                <Trainers name="VisitorPolicyID" value="ETR1234123"></Trainers>
            </Trainers>
            <Managers>
                <visitorstate>InProgress</visitorstate>
                <visitorrenewal lastupdated="2022-04-02"></visitorrenewal>
                <administrator>ROH</administrator>
                <carrier>Verizon</carrier>
                <carriernetwork>Verizon</carriernetwork>
                <carriergroupservice>Nokia</carriergroupservice>
                <programID>E3-ROH</programID>
                <RecordSystem>ATServer</RecordSystem>
                <ZipCode>ES2421</ZipCode>
                <SignerZipCode>ES2421</SignerZipCode>
                <RecieverZipCode>ES2421</RecieverZipCode>
                <version>19</version>
                <archived>false</archived>
                <SignalID>A3-213-3412</SignalID>
                <NetworkID>ProNetwork</NetworkID>
                <NetworkLocationID>ES2421</NetworkLocationID>
                <dataitem name="ProcessingVisitorId" value="Interior"></dataitem>
                <dataitem name="ProcessingVisitingInstance" value="eft-6"></dataitem>
                <Highlights>
                    <Highlight name="ScreenLock" value="true"></Highlight>
                    <Highlight name="locked" value="true"></Highlight>
                </Highlights>
            </Managers>'''
```

and I want to extract the tags, elements and the text inside the each tags into a DataFrame. I want to avoid using XML parser because I am trying to validate each individual tags.  Basically I have a list of strings:

```
list_of_search_elements = [VisitorID, VisitorNumber, ServerIndex, VisitorPolicyID, visitorrenewal, carriernetwork, ZipCode, version, NetworkLocationID, ProcessingVisitingInstance, ScreenLock]
```

and I want to find each of these elements in the XML file and validate that these are present and correct in the XML File.

Here is my attempt:

Defining the BeautifulSoup:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(xmlfile,'lxml')
```

I take individual tags from the xml file and them make it into a list:

```
list_of_tags = []
for tag in bs.findAll(True):
   list_of_tags.append(tag.name)
```

Now I divide individual tags into individual sections and move them to a list:

```
xml_section = []
for tags in list_of_tags:
    for x in soup.find(tags):
        xml_section.append(x)
```

Now I am generating parent tags:

```
parent_tags = []
for r in range(0, len(xml_section)):
    parent_tags.append(xml_section[r].name)
```

and lastly i am getting each section's individual tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

individual_tags = []
for i in range (0,len(xml_section)):
    try:
        individual_tags.append([tag.name for tag in xml_section[i].find_all()])
    except Exception as e:
        individual_tags.append('Null')
```

After this I have no idea what to do. I feel like I am over thinking this and this should have a straightforward solution.

Ideally I want a solution:

| Group | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trainers | VisitorID | NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231 |
| Trainers | VisitorNumber | BR-76594823-009922 |
| Trainers | ServerIndex | 213122 |
| Trainers | VisitorPolicyID | ETR1234123 |
| Managers | visitorrenewal | 2022-04-02 |
| Managers | carriernetwork | Verizon |
| Managers | ZipCode | ES2421 |
| Managers | version | 19 |
| Managers | NetworkLocationID | ES2421 |
| Managers | ProcessingVisitingInstance | eft-6 |
| Highlights | ScreenLock | true |

Comment: First, you are already using a parser. Then the wanted items list contains elements and attributes that have different handling in XML. Attributes can be obtained with an XPath like `//Trainers[@name="VisitorID"]/@value`

Comment: All attributes: `//Trainers/@*`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """\
<doc>

<Trainers>
    <Trainers name="VisitorID" value="NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231"></Trainers>
    <Trainers name="VisitorNumber" value="BR-76594823-009922"></Trainers>
    <Trainers name="ServerIndex" value="213122"></Trainers>
    <Trainers name="VisitorPolicyID" value="ETR1234123"></Trainers>
</Trainers>
<Managers>
    <visitorstate>InProgress</visitorstate>
    <visitorrenewal lastupdated="2022-04-02"></visitorrenewal>
    <administrator>ROH</administrator>
    <carrier>Verizon</carrier>
    <carriernetwork>Verizon</carriernetwork>
    <carriergroupservice>Nokia</carriergroupservice>
    <programID>E3-ROH</programID>
    <RecordSystem>ATServer</RecordSystem>
    <ZipCode>ES2421</ZipCode>
    <SignerZipCode>ES2421</SignerZipCode>
    <RecieverZipCode>ES2421</RecieverZipCode>
    <version>19</version>
    <archived>false</archived>
    <SignalID>A3-213-3412</SignalID>
    <NetworkID>ProNetwork</NetworkID>
    <NetworkLocationID>ES2421</NetworkLocationID>
    <dataitem name="ProcessingVisitorId" value="Interior"></dataitem>
    <dataitem name="ProcessingVisitingInstance" value="eft-6"></dataitem>
    <Highlights>
        <Highlight name="ScreenLock" value="true"></Highlight>
        <Highlight name="locked" value="true"></Highlight>
    </Highlights>
</Managers>

</doc>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

data = []
for t in soup.select("Trainers > Trainers[name][value]"):
    data.append({"Group": "Trainers", "Name": t["name"], "Value": t["value"]})

for t in soup.select("Managers > *"):
    if t.name.lower() in {"highlights", "dataitem"}:
        continue
    elif t.name.lower() == 'visitorrenewal':
        data.append({"Group": "Managers", "Name": t.name, "Value": t['lastupdated']})
    else:
        data.append({"Group": "Managers", "Name": t.name, "Value": t.text})

for t in soup.select("Managers > dataitem[name][value]"):
    data.append({"Group": "Managers", "Name": t["name"], "Value": t["value"]})

for t in soup.select("Managers > Highlights > Highlight[name][value]"):
    data.append({"Group": "Highlights", "Name": t["name"], "Value": t["value"]})


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Group                        Name                  Value
0     Trainers                   VisitorID  NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231
1     Trainers               VisitorNumber     BR-76594823-009922
2     Trainers                 ServerIndex                 213122
3     Trainers             VisitorPolicyID             ETR1234123
4     Managers                visitorstate             InProgress
5     Managers              visitorrenewal             2022-04-02
6     Managers               administrator                    ROH
7     Managers                     carrier                Verizon
8     Managers              carriernetwork                Verizon
9     Managers         carriergroupservice                  Nokia
10    Managers                   programID                 E3-ROH
11    Managers                RecordSystem               ATServer
12    Managers                     ZipCode                 ES2421
13    Managers               SignerZipCode                 ES2421
14    Managers             RecieverZipCode                 ES2421
15    Managers                     version                     19
16    Managers                    archived                  false
17    Managers                    SignalID            A3-213-3412
18    Managers                   NetworkID             ProNetwork
19    Managers           NetworkLocationID                 ES2421
20    Managers         ProcessingVisitorId               Interior
21    Managers  ProcessingVisitingInstance                  eft-6
22  Highlights                  ScreenLock                   true
23  Highlights                      locked                   true
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below scrapes a XML file named 'xmlfile.xml' which contains the data you mentioned in your post and creates two dictionaries, one for the Trainers and one for Managers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Trainers_Labels = ['visitorid','visitornumber','serverindex','visitorpolicyid']
Managers_Labels_1 = ['visitorstate','administrator','carrier','carriernetwork','carriergroupservice','programid','recordsystem','zipcode','signerzipcode','recieverzipcode','version','archived','signalid','networkid','networklocationid']
Managers_Labels_2 = ['visitorrenewal','processingvisitorid','processingvisitinginstance','screenlock','locked']

with open('xmlfile.xml') as file:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(file,'lxml')

Trainer_values = []
for trainer in bs.find_all('trainers'):
    Trainer_values.append(trainer.get('value'))
Trainer_values.pop(0)
Trainers = dict(zip(Trainers_Labels,Trainer_values))

Managers_Values = []
for i in Managers_Labels_1:
    value = bs.find(i)
    Managers_Values.append(value.string)

for date in bs.find_all('visitorrenewal'):
    Managers_Values.append(date.get('lastupdated'))

for data in bs.find_all('dataitem'):
    Managers_Values.append(data.get('value'))

for highlight in bs.find_all('highlight'):
    Managers_Values.append(highlight.get('value'))

Manager_Labels = Managers_Labels_1 + Managers_Labels_2
Managers = dict(zip(Manager_Labels,Managers_Values))
```

Then you can reuse this code and make iterates for the number of files you have and can easily access the data through the dictionary.